Electron Apple Notarisation
I am runnning persistent notarization issues with my macOS Electron application.
Despite multiple attempts to resolve these issues, the notarization status remains "Invalid," and the errors in the report are consistent.
What I'm doing
Sign the code like this
codesign --sign "Apple Distribution: Name Lastname (123456)" --deep --force --timestamp=auto path/to/Application.app
I then get: Application.app: replacing existing signature
I then verify the signing with:
codesign --verify --deep --strict --verbose=4 path/to/Application.app
I then get: --prepared:/path/to/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/SomeFramework.framework --validated:/path/to/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/SomeFramework.framework --prepared:/path/to/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/AnotherFramework.framework --validated:/path/to/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/AnotherFramework.framework Application.app: valid on disk Application.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
I then build:
npm build
I then package:
zip -r Application.zip Application.app
I then upload:
xcrun notarytool submit Application.zip --apple-id your-apple-id --team-id your-team-id --password your-app-specific-password
Then I check for status and I get:
Successfully received submission info createdDate: 2024-08-15T18:21:31.520Z id: 55daf39a-4be9-4dd6-a490-1890d33f9e75 name: Application.zip status: Invalid
In the report generated I get issues like:
"path": "path/to/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/SomeFramework.framework/SomeFramework", "message": "The signature of the binary is invalid.", "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087735", "architecture": "arm64"
and
"path": "path/to/Application.app/Contents/Frameworks/SomeFramework.framework/Versions/Current/Helpers/chrome_crashpad_handler", "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.", "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087733", "architecture": "arm64"
What am I doing wrong? I tried signing each issue separately and rerun the entire process, it's not working.

Opera 89 uses chrome_crashpad_handler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78876976/electron-apple-notarisation/78877072

Notably, other ones as an app are in OS which it is for among others, and in U4. And in Sublime Text 3 build 4180.

How I Solved My MacOS Electron App Notarization Issues (And Why This Is My First Answer)
I recently ran into a similar issue while working on a macOS Electron application, and after a lot of troubleshooting, I managed to get everything notarized successfully. Since this is my first question to answer here, and I just started my account today, I thought it would be a great opportunity to share what I learned and hopefully help others facing the same frustration.
Here’s a breakdown of the potential problems and solutions based on what worked for me:

1. Invalid Signature:
One of the first hurdles I encountered was with the invalid signatures on some frameworks within the app. The issue turned out to be related to the way these components were being signed.
Instead of using the --deep flag (which caused more harm than good), I had to individually sign each framework and binary from the innermost components to the main app bundle. This method ensures every part is signed correctly and recognized during the notarization process.
2. Missing Secure Timestamp:
Another issue that popped up was related to a missing secure timestamp, especially for binaries like chrome_crashpad_handler. It’s crucial to include the --timestamp flag when signing all binaries, as it guarantees that the notarization service sees them as valid.
3. Archive Creation:
Initially, I was using the zip command to package my app, but that led to issues during notarization. I switched to using the ditto command, which preserves all necessary file attributes, and that solved the problem. Here’s the command I used:
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent Application.app Application.zip

 4. Debugging Tips:
If you’re still stuck, try resigning the components with the correct flags and use tools like `rcodesign` to verify that everything, including the Hardened Runtime, is set up properly. [This extra step][2] helped me catch a few overlooked issues.

I hope my recommendations help you avoid the headaches I went through. Let me know if you need further clarification or more details!

Thank you. I tried this again. I think it was similar to what I did but just in case, I downloaded the notarisation report again, signed each issue separately, repackaged everything, zipped it with ditto, and uploaded. I still get:
Waiting for processing to complete.
Current status: Invalid...............................
Processing complete
id: ef0cdcaf-dcf1-4c3d-9d36-4e79b9d41b1c
status: Invalid
If I had to guess - the report will show the exact same issues as the previous report. That's where I'm stuck :)

This question does not follow the rules of the site because it is not actually a question. Please reformulate it as a true question. And then try to answer it to your own question by clicking on the respective button. If you do not separate your question from your answer, it is likely your question will be voted to be closed.

Also Opera 89 uses chrome_crashpad_handler.

Notably, other ones as an app are in OS which it is for among others, and in U4. And in Sublime Text 3 build 4180.

I was banging my head with this problem for the last day. What worked for me was to issue all my certificates not through developer.apple.com, but through XCode by going to Settings/Accounts/Manage Certificates, and issuing all types of certificates. I had deleted all my certificates from the keychain before that and issued new ones, but maybe that was an overkill. After that I added the environment variables APPLE_API_KEY, APPLE_API_KEY_ID and APPLE_API_ISSUER, which I got from here: https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/integrations/api, and the app was signed and notarized successfully when i ran electron-builder.
